# Is there an in alternative to using ParameterSplit in revit api c# 2021?

Tags: c#, revit-api, autodesk

I'm trying to create a method that splits rebar in Revit. I noticed that ParameterSplit is used in the 2015 API docs, Does anyone know if there is an alternative?

The code snip is as below with geocurve being type Curve

```
Curve[] curves = geocurve.ParameterSplit(geocurve.ComputeNormalizedParameter(geocurve.ComputeClosestPoints(curve, true, true, true, out IList<ClosestPointsPairBetweenTwoCurves> resultList)));
```

I also checked the new updated changes in the below link, there doesn't seem to be anything to use to split the rebar?

https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2018-api.html#2.11

Thanking you in advance